# Release lock correctly within try clauses

Tags: python, locking

I have a function in which I release a lock. However before it does so, it calls another function in which an exception may occur. How can I handle this so that the lock is released/handled well? I want the lock to be released either way.

I have the below but don't know if it is a good way to do things:

```
def a():
    try:
        #code here
        b()
        #more code
    finally:
        #lock released here
    return 0


def b():
    try:
        #code 
        #Exception happens here
        #code
    catch:
        print "sample warning"
        return 0
    return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't see any problem with your code.
The finally will always be done, so your lock will always be released.

Comment: All right thanks Jacques, never really used them before so didn't know if there was a better way of doing it.